# Adding duplicates into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imdb

I would like to be able to sort my array so I don't have duplicates into my "Recently-Viewed" section. The recently viewed section works fine except that it breaks when I add a duplicate. So I want to be able to sort my array so it doesn't break. I'm not really sure how to implement a sort function. Do I use filter or what do I do? I'm really confused.

[image: picture of problem]

My code:

```jsx
const [tvShow, setTVShow] = useState([]);
const [recentlyViewed, setRecentlyViewed] = useState([]);

const getMovieRequest = async () => {
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=1e08baad3bc3eca3efdd54a0c80111b9&language=en-US&page=1`;
    
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJson = await response.json();

    setTVShow(responseJson.results)

};

useEffect(() => {
    getMovieRequest();
},[]);

useEffect(() => {
    const recentlyMovies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-movie-app-favourites')
    );
    
    if (recentlyMovies) {
        setRecentlyViewed(recentlyMovies.slice(0,5));
    }
}, []);

const saveToLocalStorage = (items) => {
    localStorage.setItem('react-movie-app-favourites', JSON.stringify(items))
};

const addRecentlyViewed = (movie) => {
    const newRecentlyViewed = [movie, ...recentlyViewed]
    setRecentlyViewed(newRecentlyViewed.slice(0,5));
    saveToLocalStorage(newRecentlyViewed);

    if (newRecentlyViewed > 5) {
        newRecentlyViewed.pop();
    }
};
```

Thank you guys in advance. I'm new to React and I find this very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) constructor and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
uniq = [...new Set(array)];
```

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        const recentlyMovies = [...new Set(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-movie-app-favourites')))];
        
        if (recentlyMovies) {
            setRecentlyViewed(recentlyMovies.slice(0,5));
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to Implement this but it does not change anything.

Comment: It sadly did not change anything :/ Can still add duplicates.

Comment: When you refresh the page did the duplicates disappear ?

Comment: No, it stays. :/

Comment: You'll still be able to add duplicates to the array as the `useEffect` dependency array is empty, meaning it will run once on mount only.
You'll have to refactor this to run every time the `recentlyViewed` array is updated. In your case, changing the line `setRecentlyViewed(newRecentlyViewed.slice(0,5));` to be `setRecentlyViewed([...new Set(newRecentlyViewed)].slice(0,5));` should work.

Comment: @JamesHooper comment should help you.

Comment: You can help other people in the community when set answer as correct ;)